# display: none; not affecting div after applying media query

Tags: css

```
    @media all and (min-width: 641px) {
  .small-screen {
    display: none;
    }
  }


<div class="small-screen">
  <h1 id="club-offcial-name-small">Hercules Club</h1>
  <h2 id="no-training-small"><q>Aqui nadie entrena</q></h2>
  </div>
```

.small-screen is still there when going above 640px.

Guys, total noob here, stuck badly here :/

Comment: I am in chrome via Brackets... So, if its a browser issue, how can i fix it? Use different text edit?

Comment: can you show your css styles for `small-screen` below 641px?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a browser support problem. In Chrome (codepen) it works perfect for me. Which browser are you using? Here is a table of the media query support: http://caniuse.com/#search=%40media

```
Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWYLBJ
```

Comment: Do you have the CSS in a different file?

Comment: Or do you have a "style-tag" around the CSS?

Comment: I have few files for css so i don't get lost, but this particular one comes from responsive file in css folder

<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/responsive.css">

Comment: With <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/responsive.css"> it must work if it's not a browser support problem

Answer (score -1):

Ok I think I know your problem. You need to put a style-tag around the css code in the  like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
@media all and (min-width: 641px) {
.small-screen {
display: none;
}
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="small-screen">
  <h1 id="club-offcial-name-small">Hercules Club</h1>
  <h2 id="no-training-small"><q>Aqui nadie entrena</q></h2>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it did took it off, but any idea why its not working in the css file, as other rules are applied without issues from that file

Comment: are you sure that  the "CSS" is in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: I meant the "CSS" Folder sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
 .small-screen {
 display: none!important;
   }
 }
```

If you've found it helpful please mark this as the accepted answer to your question. Thanks.